# Why does this JS code cannot change the class name

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="cube">
    <div id="top"><strong>top</strong></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var cube=document.getElementById('cube'),
    top=document.getElementById('top'),
    wrap=document.getElementById('wrap');
cube.onclick=function(){
    top.classList.toggle("click");
    alert("done");
};
</script>
```

When click the cube,I want to change the class name,But it doesn't work

Where is the problem?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of it please.

Comment: IE 9 and older do not support the `classList` attribute.  What browser and version are you running this on?  What goes wrong?  Are you getting a specific error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the variable `top`, it's a reference to `window.top` <s>inside the event handler in your case</s>

```
var cube = document.getElementById('cube'),
    top_ = document.getElementById('top'),
    wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
cube.onclick = function() {
    top_.classList.toggle("click");
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwBYE/1/)

Comment: Actually, it's a reference to `window.top` even at the very scope it's defined - adding `console.log(top)` right after _local_ variables declaration proves it.

Comment: @raina77ow - seems it is, I just logged it inside the onclick and noticed it was the window.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to rename the variable - just make that one, well, *really local*:

```
(function(){
var cube = document.getElementById('cube'),
    top = document.getElementById('top'),
    wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

cube.onclick = function(){
    console.log(top);
    top.classList.toggle("click");
    alert("done");
};
})();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rPD5H/). The difference, of course, is that the whole block is wrapped in [**IIFE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), so all the variables declared within it are defined in the scope of this function. In other words, now they're *really local*. )

In the original snippet, all `var` statements were placed at the outmost - global - scope. So they're processed by JS as if you were trying to augment the same-named properties of global object - `window`, that is. As `window.top` is a special read-only property, its value actually won't be changed.